# Bugs by Design?

Tags: facebook, bug-tracking

I've subscribed to the Developer Blog Weekly Digest where the weekly stats lists number of bugs reported, fixed, etc. What does "bugs by design" mean? I thought bugs were unintentional,  meaning the code is syntactically correct but produces an unintentional result. Rather new category of bugs for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means the bugs, that were closed with reason "by design".

Let's suppose you've filled a "bug" that describes some "strange" behaviour (you think so), but in fact it has been done intentionally.

In this case bug is closed and marked as "by design"

First googled example: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/316854721738536/

As you can see - someone found that if message was posted by 3rd party app - it lacks "share button". But it was implemented in this way intentionally, thus this behaviour is "by design" not a real bug.